# setOnCheckedChangeListener outside of onCreateView

Tags: java, android, object

I'm new to Java and I don't know how to google this.

What I want to do is "outsourcing" the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to it's own function in the `SleepTimeReminderFragment` class so that it is not inside the `onCreateView` function with the usual new `Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener` but rather in it's own, like I tried to show how I mean this, by trying how I think this should work, but that gives me errors. So is this at all possible or did I just do something wrong? The error is with the `@override` as it states that I cannot do that there. See ### at 1), 2) and 3).

```
public class SleepTimeReminderFragment extends Fragment {

    // ### This 1)
    Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener swEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL;

    public SleepTimeReminderFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sleep_time_reminder, container, false);

        Switch swEnSleepTimeReminderMod = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.swEnSleepTimeReminderMod);
        swEnSleepTimeReminderMod.setOnCheckedChangeListener(swEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL);

        // ### function that I want to "outsource" 2)
        /*swEnSleepTimeReminderMod.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // set all view items but this switch to enabled
                } else {
                    // set all view items but this switch to not enabled
                }
            }
        });*/

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    // ### what I guessed this "outsourcing" would have to look like 3)
    private Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener getSwEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // set all view items but this switch to enabled
            } else {
                // set all view items but this switch to not enabled
            }
        }
        return swEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you **don't** want to use an **anonymous** inner class, you have to use a non-anonymous class, that means **it has to have a name** (in my example  `MyListener`).

You also have to create a `new` instance at some point (I did that in the constructor, but it can be anywhere before the usage).

Example:

```
public class SleepTimeReminderFragment extends Fragment {

    Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener swEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL;

    public SleepTimeReminderFragment() {
         swEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL = new MyListener();
    }

    //omitted onCreate

    private class MyListener implements Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // set all view items but this switch to enabled
            } else {
                // set all view items but this switch to not enabled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Sidenote: If you are using Java 8, you can just pass a method reference to setOnCheckedChangeListener. At the time of this post android has only experimental Java 8 support.*

Comment: Thank you, this works fine, just the `return swEnSleepTimeReminderModOCCL;` must be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To "outsource" the listener function for `Switch`, your class needs to implement `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` interface and override the method `onCheckedChanged()`

```
public class SleepTimeReminderFragment extends Fragment 
    implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{ //implement interface here

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //do your stuff here
        swEnSleepTimeReminderMod.setOnCheckedChangedListener(SleepTimeReminderFragment.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // set all view items but this switch to enabled
        } else {
            // set all view items but this switch to not enabled
        }
    }
}
```